# How do .dae Files Store Mesh Data?

Tags: c++, xml, collada

I'm attempting to read in a mesh from a .dae file to a DirectX project using TinyXML and I'm having difficulty understanding how .dae files store the mesh data.

I believe I have found where the mesh data is stored: inside the tag `<library_geometries>` there is the following code:

```
<library_geometries>
    <geometry id="Tall_bodyShape" name="Tall_bodyShape">
        <mesh>
            <source id="Tall_bodyShape-positions" name="position">
                <float_array id="Tall_bodyShape-positions-array" count="2910"> *** lots of numbers *** </float_array>
                <technique_common>
                    <accessor source="#Tall_bodyShape-positions-array" count="970" stride="3">
                        <param name="X" type="float"/>
                        <param name="Y" type="float"/>
                        <param name="Z" type="float"/>
                    </accessor>
                </technique_common>
            </source>
            <source id="Tall_bodyShape-normals" name="normal">
                <float_array id="Tall_bodyShape-normals-array" count="3948"> *** lots of numbers *** </float_array>
                <technique_common>
                    <accessor source="#Tall_bodyShape-normals-array" count="1316" stride="3">
                        <param name="X" type="float"/>
                        <param name="Y" type="float"/>
                        <param name="Z" type="float"/>
                    </accessor>
                </technique_common>
            </source>
            <source id="Tall_bodyShape-UVChannel_1" name="UVChannel_1">
                <float_array id="Tall_bodyShape-UVChannel_1-array" count="2892"> *** lots of numbers *** </float_array>
                <technique_common>
                    <accessor source="#Tall_bodyShape-UVChannel_1-array" count="1446" stride="2">
                        <param name="S" type="float"/>
                        <param name="T" type="float"/>
                    </accessor>
                </technique_common>
            </source>
            <vertices id="Tall_bodyShape-vertices">
                <input semantic="POSITION" source="#Tall_bodyShape-positions"/>
            </vertices>
            <triangles material="Tall_bodySG" count="1883">
                <input semantic="VERTEX" source="#Tall_bodyShape-vertices" offset="0"/>
                <input semantic="NORMAL" source="#Tall_bodyShape-normals" offset="1"/>
                <input semantic="TEXCOORD" source="#Tall_bodyShape-UVChannel_1" offset="2" set="0"/>
                <p> *** lots of numbers *** </p>
            </triangles>
        </mesh>
        <extra>
            <technique profile="MAYA">
                <double_sided>1</double_sided>
            </technique>
        </extra>
    </geometry>
</library_geometries>
```

So the verticies are stored inside the `<source>` tag named `"position"`, the normals are stored within the `<source>` tag named `"normal"` and the `<triangles>` tag lists which UV coordinates and normals are associated with which vertex.

I presume that the triangles are listed in either a 'line' or 'stripped' method but it doesn't say which and whichever I try, they both display a jagged, balled mess of triangles.

Does anyone know if there's some other mesh data that I've missed that's in another part of the dae or where I might've gone wrong? If necessary, I can post the function in which I load in the mesh data.

EDIT: Additional note: I'm certain that the .dae file is correct and valid as it can be correctly loaded into the PhyreEngine (I'm using a .dae that I used for a university project last year).

Comment: You have to apply the transformations in the scene.

Comment: Do you mean in the section with the tag `library_visual_scenes` that lists a load of stuff about catrig and bones? The only other stuff I could find was about animation. I thought that, because the 3D model is a single mesh (the artist extruded it from a single box) that it would be in a full pose, not overlapping, when just the verticies are extracted.

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is a relatively old question, but since it hasn't really been answered, I'll take a crack at it for posterity.

You are correct that the positions, normals, etc. are stored as float arrays in the `<source>` elements.  The `<p>` ("primitive") element stores the indices for the three inputs listed immediately prior within the `<triangles>` element.  That is, the first 3 integers (e.g. "0 0 0") point to the appropriate VERTEX, NORMAL, and TEXCOORD (UVChannel) values for the first vertex.  That it's in a `<triangles>` element indicates that each set of 3 vertices (9 index integers) describes a new triangle, so none of the indices is reused.  If the geometry were set up to use strips (reusing the previous 2 vertices) or fans (reusing the first and previous vertices), the parent element would be called `<tristrips>` or `<trifans>`, respectively.  The second set of 3 integers (e.g. "1 1 1") describe the second vertex in the first triangle, and so on.

Also, as @jterrace points out, the geometry coordinates are internal to the object described in the geometry.  To place the object correctly in the scene as a whole, you'll have to apply the appropriate transformations (`<translate>`, `<rotate>`, etc.) from the scene as described in `<library_visual_scenes>`.

Comment: I think it would only be 7 integers not 9 because the uv only has 2 not 3.

Answer (score 2):

I used assimp to load mesh data. The explanation and code is here:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ClqnhYAYtcY
http://www.mediafire.com/download/006lk0xomup7laq/assimpLinux.zip